# Reading whitespaces inside of a list of strings

Tags: python

I'm having a problem trying to count whitespaces in a list in python.

Here's my code

```
Data = ''
index = 0
num_words = 0

# Open a file for reading.
infile = open('article.txt', 'r')

# Read the contents of the file into a list.
data = infile.readlines()

# Strip the \n from each element.
while index < len(data):
    data[index] = data[index].rstrip('\n')
    index += 1

for ch in data:
    if ch.isspace():
        num_words += 1
# Close the file.
infile.close()

# Print the contents of the list.
print(num_words)
```

The contents of the article.txt is just a list of sentences so the list is just a list of strings such as:

```
data = ['this is sentence one.', 'this is sentence two.' , 'this is      sentence three.' , 'this is sentence four.' , 'this is sentence five.' , 'this is sentence six.' ]
```

I think I know what the problem is because I did:

```
print(ch)
```

Which results in 'false' getting printed 6 times. I'm thinking this is because the for loop is searching to see if the whole string is a space rather than checking for spaces inside of the string.

I know I could just do:

```
data = infile.read()
```

But I need each line in a list. Is there anything I can change so the for loop searches for spaces in each string in the list or am I out of luck?

Comment: You are right about the cause of your problem. You need two nested for-loops. The outer goes through the list items (strings) the inner through each character of one list item.

Comment: why not simply `"some data in a line".count(" ")` ? Or do you need other whitespaces as well?

Comment: I was able to solve this by following Michaels recommendation of creating an inner for-loop. Thanks!

Comment: OP: You are counting words not spaces, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a handy method for that on strings, called `str.split`.  When passed no arguments, it will split on whitespace.  If you count the items in the resulting list, you will have the number of words.

Handles multiple spaces:

```
>>> line = "this is     some    string."
>>> len(line.split())
4
```

Handles empty lines:

```
>>> line = "   "
>>> len(line.split())
0
```

Handles extra space before and after:

```
>>> line = "   space before and after.   "
>>> len(line.split())
4
```

---

Here is some sample code:

```
lines = 0
words = 0

with open('yourfile', 'rt') as yourfile:
  for line in yourfile:
    lines += 1
    words += len(line.split())
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks a lot better than my solution.